# Angularjs unable to set the method on click of button using service calls

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and looking for some quick help in my code. 
My requirement is that on click of button, I need to pass an array of items to my controller1. I have another form which has other another controller2.In controller2 I have an array of objects. What I require is I need to pass the array of items from Controller1 and pushed to to array of objects to Controller2. I have write a custom serivce but I ended with exception - Can not read property set undefined.

I am sharing  my code as

Front HTML
// Sample is an array consits of objects

```
  <button class="submit" style="margin-top: 10px;"ng-click="apply(sample)">APPLY</button>
```

// Controller 1

```
$scope.apply = function(item){
               myCustomService.set(item);
               console.log("Item is captured "+$scope.item);
               $scope.item= [];
            }
```

// Service call

```
angular.module('app').service('myCustomService',function(){
$scope.sorabh = [];
$scope.shaan = [];

return {

        get: function() {
            return sorabh;
        },
        set: function(name) {
            $scope.shaan = name;
            for(var i = 0;i<$scope.shaan.length;i++){
            $scope.sorabh.push($scope.shaan[i]);
            }
            alert("data pushed");
        }
    };

});
```

// Controller 2

In this controller using the service get method I will get the array of items and will push the array of objects in it.

Please help

Comment: Is your controller1 and controller2 bound html separate from each other or does one go inside the other? If you can post your entire HTML, we can look at how your controller share scopes or not